# How to call virtual method without polymorphic effect?

Tags: c++, methods, polymorphism, virtual

I have reference `ref`:

```
Foo &ref = ..
```

I would like to call a method `ref.say()` which is defined as virtual in `Foo` and I know for sure it is overridden in child classes (because I wrote them as well).

However I would like to call `say` as if it was **not** polymorphic, so the version which is defined in Foo, not in child classes.

How to do it?

One thing that comes to my mind is to take pointer of `ref`, than dereference it and this trick should kill polymorphism, but I am not sure if this is guaranteed to take desired effect.

*Please note, I am not sitting inside Foo or any of its child, the Foo tree is external structure from my current POV.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
ref.Foo::say();
```

This what you looking for?

Comment: Great, I was totally unaware of such syntax.

Comment: @greenoldman you've probably seen usage like `Base::foo()` before, to call the base's implementation. This really just means `this->Base::foo()`, because the `this` is implicit.

Comment: @Simple, thank you. I thought of this syntax as kind of scope setting.